# Função para incluir e excluir itens de acordo com table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho esta função:

```
 foreach (var item in obj.valores)
        {
            var ver = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(r => r.ProdutoID == item.ProdutoID && r.FornecedorID == item.FornecedorID).Select(r => r.Id).Single();
            if (ver == 0)
            {
                ProdutosFornecedores a = new ProdutosFornecedores();
                a.FornecedorID = item.FornecedorID;
                a.ProdutoID = item.ProdutoID;
                db.Add(a);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return Json(new { resultado = 1 });
```

Que recebe os dados da tabela, e inclui no banco, corretamente, porém eu quero que ele verifique com os dados do banco.
Exemplo, no banco tem o id 1 e 2, e eu estou incluindo o 2 e o 4, então eu preciso que ele exclua o 1, continue o 2, e inclua o 4. 
Pensei em excluir todos e adicionar novamente, porém creio que é algo desnecessário, é só questão de tratar, só não estou conseguindo pensar a melhor maneira de fazer isso, pois após o resultado é realizado o `submit`.

Eu cheguei nestes dados :

```
foreach (var item in obj.valores)
            {
                var listaAtual = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Where(r => r.ProdutoID == item.ProdutoID).Select(r => r.FornecedorID).ToList();
                var novaLista = obj.valores.Select(a => a.FornecedorID).ToList();
                var remover = listaAtual.Where(a => !novaLista.Contains(a));
                var adicionar = novaLista.Where(a => !listaAtual.Contains(a));
                foreach (var c in remover)
                {
                    var remove = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Single(d => d.ProdutoID == item.ProdutoID && d.FornecedorID == c);
                    if (remove != null)
                    {
                        db.ProdutosFornecedores.Remove(remove);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                foreach (var c in adicionar)
                {
                    ProdutosFornecedores a = new ProdutosFornecedores();
                    a.FornecedorID = c;
                    a.ProdutoID = item.ProdutoID;
                    db.Add(a);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Porém não está funcionando da forma correta, o que está sendo feito de errado?
Se já existe o id = 1, e na tabela eu incluo o id = 2, ele exclui o 1 e inclui só o 2, eu preciso que permaneça o 1, e inclui o 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom eu faria o seguinte.
Compara as duas listas para saber o que remover e o que adicionar. veja o exemplo:

```
void Main()
{
    var listaAtual = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    var novaLista = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 4,6,7};
    var remover = listaAtual.Where(a => !novaLista.Contains(a)).Select(a => a);
    var adicionar = novaLista.Where(a => !listaAtual.Contains(a)).Select(a => a);
    foreach(var c in remover){
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("===");
    foreach (var c in adicionar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
Resultado:
3
5
===
7
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta na forma que cheguei, como posso fazer a comparação, criei as duas listas, a lista atual, e a nova lista.

Comment: Sua lógica não faz sentido, se na tabela existe o 1 e vc adiciono o 2. Na lista de adição sempre tem que vir os que vão permanecer e os novos, assim vc evita excluir que já estão. e excluir apenas os que saíram.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.